# How to use nginx capture group to attach prefix to rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am currently trying to rewrite four paths in kubernetes ingress.

The three are done but the static file path is a bit tricky.

My frontend path is `/$1` -> `/(.*)` web-front-cluster-ip-service

I also need to rewrite all `/img/$1` -> `/img/(.*)` apollo-api-cluster-ip-service

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: servers-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: apollo-api-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 4000
            path: /apollo_api/?(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: rest-api-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 5000
            path: /rest/?(.*)
          - backend:
              serviceName: web-front-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 6000
            path: /?(.*)
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: statics-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /img/$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: apollo-api-cluster-ip-service
            servicePort: 4000
          path: /img/?$(.*)
```

My current setting looks like above but for unknown reason, I am not able to reach the route configured by the second route.

So what I am trying to do instead is to combine two routes together and provide prefix to capture group that matches `/img`

if I do

```
      - backend:
          serviceName: apollo-api-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 6000
        path: /?(.*)
```

it will route everything to `apollo-api` when I need any route that does not start with `/img` to be routed to `web-front`

so I need something like below

```
      - backend:
          serviceName: apollo-api-cluster-ip-service
          servicePort: 4000
        path: /img?(.*) <- somehow add /img to $(.*) because currently it rewrites `/img/static.png` -> `/static.png` but I need `/img/static.png` -> `/img/static.png`.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Rewrite Target documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/rewrite#rewrite-target):

> !!! attention Starting in Version 0.22.0, ingress definitions using
> the annotation nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target are not
> backwards compatible with previous versions. In Version 0.22.0 and
> beyond, any substrings within the request URI that need to be passed
> to the rewritten path must explicitly be defined in a capture group.
>
> !!! note Captured groups are saved in numbered placeholders, chronologically, in the form $1, $2 ... $n. These placeholders can be
> used as parameters in the rewrite-target annotation.

So I suppose your second ingress should look like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: statics-ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /img/$2
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: apollo-api-cluster-ip-service
            servicePort: 4000
          path: /img(/|$)(.*)
```

In this case `$2` will reflect `(.*)`